# PHP loop to generate array

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I am not so familiar but sure there should be some way to shorten my code. I am having multi-dimention array as below.

```
return array(

    'save' => 'here is the save message',

    'options' => array(

        // section for item 1
        array(
            'name' => 'Item 1',
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'item_1_type_1',
        ),

        array(
            'name' => 'Item 2',
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'item_1_type_2',
        ),

        array(
            'name' => 'Item 3',
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'item_1_type_3',
        ),


        // section for item 2
        array(
            'name' => 'Item 1',
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'item_2_type_1',
        ),

        array(
            'name' => 'Item 2',
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'item_2_type_2',
        ),

        array(
            'name' => 'Item 3',
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => 'item_2_type_3',
        ),

        // here I also may add more fields aprart from loop
        // but that would be an array with the same format

        'submit' => array(
                    'name' => 'Save Options',
                    'id' => 'save_theme_options'
                ),
    ),

);
```

Now I have total 10 items (please refer id) and each item has 10 fields (in reference code only 3). So if I would write code for each field it will become massive around 100 array so I am looking for some way where I can repeat loop for each item.

I hope I explained properly..

Comment: What's the desired output? Do you want to convert that array to something more structured?

Comment: I think he's rather trying to write less code. Use nested loops for it.

Comment: @PAM yes, you understood me in correct way. I am trying to make code shorter than 100s of arrays

Comment: @Lee trying to make code shorter than 100 arrays

Comment: But why? what is the input, and what is the desired output?

Comment: Believe these are WordPress theme options and output will be form fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the patterns in your data and create the code, generating these patterns, instead of writing everything by hand:

```
<?php
$array = array(
    'save' => 'here is the save message',
    'options' => array(),
);

$n = 2;
$m = 3;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; ++$i)
{
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $m; ++$j)
    {
        $element = array(
            'name' => "Item $i",
            'type' => 'text',
            'id' => "item_" . $i . "_type_$j",
            );
        array_push($array['options'], $element);
    }
}

$array['options']['submit'] = array(
    'name' => 'Save Options',
    'id' => 'save_theme_options'
    );

var_dump($array);
```

Prints:

```
array(2) {
  ["save"]=>
  string(24) "here is the save message"
  ["options"]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Item 1"
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "text"
      ["id"]=>
      string(13) "item_1_type_1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Item 1"
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "text"
      ["id"]=>
      string(13) "item_1_type_2"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Item 1"
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "text"
      ["id"]=>
      string(13) "item_1_type_3"
    }
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Item 2"
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "text"
      ["id"]=>
      string(13) "item_2_type_1"
    }
    [4]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Item 2"
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "text"
      ["id"]=>
      string(13) "item_2_type_2"
    }
    [5]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Item 2"
      ["type"]=>
      string(4) "text"
      ["id"]=>
      string(13) "item_2_type_3"
    }
    ["submit"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "Save Options"
      ["id"]=>
      string(18) "save_theme_options"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code is working fine too but can you please guide me for my confusion. Please refer my comment on Prashanth Bendra's answer

Comment: @pixelngrain Looking, sorry, was busy

Comment: @pixelngrain I looked at your conversation with Prashanth Bendra. Can you update your question, specifying, what output do you want to get? Except for that, generated by my code. Currently, it's hard to understand, what you want.

Comment: Okay give me some time I will do

Comment: @pixelngrain To achieve this, you need to set static values to the array. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. just one more query..hope last.. how can I render all these values? because when I tried with `return $array;` it's only outputs last $array obvious.. can you guide me for that..

Comment: @pixelngrain I overlooked your requirement. Seems, that submit element is inside the options in your task. Maybe, that was the issue. Answer updated.

Comment: I got output but now buttons render as a text field and not the submit button

Comment: Okay I have fixed that issue by modifying this `$array['submit'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sections = "Section1,Section2";
$itemCount = 3; // how many items you need
$generated = array(); // generated array

foreach(explode(",",$sections) as $k/*for index number*/=>$v/*section name*/)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < $itemCount; $i++)
    {
        $generated[] = array("name" => "Item ".($i+1/*starts from 0*/), "type"=> "item", "id" => "$v_$k_type_$i");          
    }
}
```